# Xamarin Database Connection Refuse

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, xamarin, sqlclient

I'm trying to get connected to my own MySQL Database over the System.Data.SqlClient but every time i'm trying i'll get in the Timeout because of the server is unreachable. I also tried the MySQL Plugin but there i also get an Error. I think that the "APP" blocks the connection.

This is my Code:

```
public void connDB() {

   SqlConnectionStringBuilder ConnString = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
   ConnString.DataSource = "[Server-IP]";
   ConnString.UserID = "[Username]";
   ConnString.Password = "[Password]";
   ConnString.InitialCatalog = "[DB-Name]";
   ConnString.ConnectTimeout = 50;

   SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(ConnString.ToString());

   sqlConn.Open();

}
```

At sqlConn.Open(); i get this message =>
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.

The Server is normally responding and my server inputs are right.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Is the server running and does it allow connections from outside localhost? Also, are you sure you should expose MySQL server directly rather than some web API to interact with it?

Comment: The Server is running and i can load data via a simple PHP script. I thought that directly is the most simple way to load data. I also tried this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UA43p46H-Bg but no success.

Comment: You really should not try to directly hit the database from a mobile device. If the device is not on the same network (like mobile data) then the database would have to be open to the internet and that is all kinds of wrong. You need a service like Web API between them as mentioned by orhtej2.